# Active class being removed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple active class for a nav item. Heres the nav.

```
<footer>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="footer-link" href="#contact" data-scroll><span class="icon-chat">         </span>Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="footer-link" href="#work" data-scroll><span class="icon-tools-2"></span>Work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="footer-link" href="#services" data-scroll><span class="icon-briefcase"></span>Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="footer-link" href="blog.html"><span class="icon-pencil"></span>Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
```

And then the js:

```
 $('a.footer-link').click(function() {
 $('a.footer-link').removeClass("active");
  return $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

Every time I change the page to the *Blog* page - the link is active, but as soon the page loads it's gone. The first three `a`'s are all on the same page and retain the 'active' class which it gets lost when the *blog page* loads.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you expect otherwise?

Comment: check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851413/how-to-keep-the-changes-made-to-dom-by-javascript-jquery-on-page-refresh

Comment: The active classes are set by a javascript (jQuery) code that handles `data-scroll` which is not set for the blog link. The blog therefore should register an active class like (pseudo:) `if page == "blog" make Active element with href "blog.html"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @DerekS you're welcome to improve the idea and post an answer. I don't have enough information from the OP code to directly pin-point the real issue.

Comment: data-scroll is for smooth scrolling on links. Blog doesn't have one cause its not the same pages as the other divs.

Comment: I've been working on a solution for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/cYqcc/21/.  It certainly works for the example you gave but it has some limitations that I am trying to fix. Let me know if you want to discuss it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

Set a class to your html body for each page, such as

```
<body class="blog">/* Your HTML*/</body>
```

And an extra class for your items, perhaps (if you don't want to use the ahref selector for styles)

```
<a class="footer-link blog"> ... </a>
```

And when you got your new page, your global JS helper function will check what to add.

```
(function () {

   var bodyClass = $('body').attr('class');

   switch (bodyClass) {
      case "blog":
         $('a.footer-link.body').addClass('active');
         break;
      default:
         /* other functions */
   };


})();
```